# Keep getting JS function undefined error

Tags: javascript

Below is my function that i am calling on asp image button client click event to confirm the deletion. i keep getting function undefined error.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function confirmDelete1() 
    {
        var bReturnValue;
        bSkipPageLoadJS = true;
        bReturnValue = window.confirm("You are about to delete the selected saved report. This          action cannot be reversed. Continue?");
        setValue(bReturnValue);
        return bReturnValue;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You have no value for bReturnValue

Comment: Does your javascript code appear in the `<head>` of your document?

Comment: Is this all of your code? If so, you don't have a setValue function. If not, can you post the rest?

Answer (score -1):

As @joews said, you haven't defined a set value function. I think this is your main issue. An example would be the following:

```
function setValue(){
  var value = arguments[0]; //this calls the value of the argument (the thing in parentheses)
  return value; 
}
```

Comment: `window.confirm` always returns true or false, so bReturnValue does have a value by the time anything is done with it.

Comment: TJon is right. "setValue(bReturnValue);" Where have you defined "function setValue(arg)"? (Argh, apparently the answer was edited...)

Comment: @joews, thanks. I had overlooked that. I hope you don't mind, but I edited my answer to include what you said in the comments. I think that is the OP's main issue.

Comment: @TJonS joews' comment, and your comment about overlooking something, suggested to me that your original answer said something else - which prompted joe to write a comment about bReturnValue.

Comment: @Katana314, right. This was joew's idea, and I have merely implemented it. My original answer had to do with a variable definition I had overlooked.